# Php, Mysql, one query find and update multiple records

Tags: php, mysql

I will run a cron job on a single php file every hour, and I need to compose a query that will do the following:

Go through each record in users table and if field "created" is older than 12 hours, update all records in status column from 0 to 2, if the filed status is 1 leave it alone.

```
created                status
=============================
2015-07-17 22:29:46    0
2015-10-25 08:25:37    1
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you:

`update users set status = 2 where status = 0 and created < now() - interval 12 hour` ?